# IntelliJ build failed but it works at second time

Tags: java, intellij-idea

It is weird that when I build my code in IntelliJ IDEA. The first time always has an internal error.

It shows like :

```
"Internal error (java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException): Unable to make protected void java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @6b4a4e18".
```

It will work for the second time. There is nothing wrong with my code because it is just a simple "hello, world". Is there anything I can do? It is so convenient I need to run twice every time.

Comment: Can you post your code here. Also, post the exact error which is shown by IntelliJ.

Comment: Which versions of the JDK and Intellij?

Comment: Did you create the project with JDK 8 or under and then change it to 9 or above? I ran into this the other day. I created a project with JDK 8 and then changed it to JDK 11. Even thought I didn't add a `module-info.java` file, IDEA wouldn't compile.